# Boolean algebra: simplify (A+B)$'C'$(C+D)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to solve / simplify the output of a logic circuit. The output is $(A+B)'C'(C+D)$

I wrote the truth table and it returns 0 in all outputs. I tried to solve it using [laws of boolean algebra](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html):

$(A+B)' = A'B'$

And $C′(C+D) = (C′C + C′D)$

$C′C = 0$ [Boolean law $A.A′ = 0$]

Does that mean $(C′C + C′D) = 0$ as well?

If that's the case, the result of the entire output would be zero. Am I right or is there any mistakes? Is there any other law applied here?

Update: I made a mistake in the truth table. It doesn't return zero in all outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C'C=0$ will not imply $C'C + C'D=0$, and $C'C + C'D=1$ when $C=0,D=1.$ 
Here is how to simplify the expression:

\begin{align}
&(A+B)'C'(C+D)\\
&\equiv(A'B')C'(C+D)\tag*{de Morgan’s Theorem}\\
&\equiv(A'B')(C'C+C'D)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv(A'B')(0+C'D)\tag*{Complement}\\
&\equiv(A'B')(C'D)\tag*{Identity}\\
\end{align}
Hence it has A'B'C'D as it's minimal CNF&DNF form.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a handy equivalence:

**Reduction**

$P(P'+Q)=PQ$

To see why this is true: note that $P$ has to be true, and hence for $P'+Q$ to be true as well, it is clear that (since $P'$ is now false), $Q$ has to be true.  We thus say that in the context of $P$, the term $P'+Q$ 'reduces' to $Q$.

You can of course derive this from more basic principles:

$P(P'+Q)=PP'+PQ=0+PQ=PQ$

but I find that having Reduction as a 1 step equivalence really makes simplification a lot faster in practice. Indeed, for your problem, we get:

$(A+B)'C'(C+D)\overset{DeMorgan, Reduction}{=}A'B'C'D$

Done!

So yes, definitely put Reduction in your handy-dandy-toolbag for Boolean logic!

Answer (score 2):

The output for the above expressing is 1 in only 1 out of the 16 possible cases, I guess you must have missed that one, let's have a look,

if $C = 1$,
$$C = 1 \implies C' = 0 \implies (A+B)′′(C+D) = 0$$

Now, if $C = 0$,
$$(A+B)′′(C+D) \equiv (A+B)′D \equiv A'B'D$$

Clearly, $A'B'D$ can be equal to 1 only when $A=0,B=0,D=1$

Therefore, $(A+B)′′(C+D) = 1$ only when $A=0,B=0,C=0,D=1$, otherwise, $(A+B)′′(C+D) = 0$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the question stating that I made a mistake in the truth table.